# Instantiated a class, but it appears referenced to null

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, groovy-2

I'm trying to instantiate an object and set a single attribute on it, which comes from a request parameter, like so :

```
println "Question text from the request :" + params.question

def question = new SurveyQuestion()
question.question = params.question

println "this is our question" + question
```

This is my output in the console :

> Question text from the request :test this is our
>   questionroosearch.SurveyQuestion : null

And this is the `SurveyQuestion` class :

```
class SurveyQuestion {

    String question

    static hasMany = [responses : SurveyQuestionResponse]
    static belongsTo = [survey: Survey]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The above seems to compile ok, however I get further classcast exceptions when I do a redirect at the end of my action, I believe this is due to the instantiating and setting of that `SurveyQuestion`, as if I comment out the above I don't get this failure behaviour.

Am I instantiating the SurveyQuestion object correctly? Why does it display as null when I print it to the console? Is that normal behaviour? At the least I'd expect it to print the object reference as Java would?

Thanks

Comment: You'll also have a problem saving that question without a Survey parent being set.

Answer (score 4):

The default `toString()` method on a domain instance will return a string which looks like `class.name: id`. As your newly created domain instance doesn't have `id` set is shows `null`.

Try overriding `toString()` in your `SurveyQuestion` domain:

```
String toString() {
    return question
}
```